# Using xpath to restore a DOM range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, actionscript, xpath, webkit

I'm trying to grasp the best approach to saving (serializing) and restoring (deserializing) a DOM selection or range. There is a post here on stringifying a range object, but it frankly doesn't really work.

The situation is an interactive text book using the Webkit view of Adobe Air. I have static (built-in) html content that the user can highlight and bookmark (annotate). This mechanism all works, but I need to be able to store and restore these annotations. I would rather not store a modified version of the DOM, but rather use the static version then reapply the users annotations that I am storing in a SQLite DB along with other needed metadata. DOM manipulation is pretty new for me, and so far my attempts to serialize a DOM::range have failed. What I realized though is that I really seem to only need the start and end containers and the start and end offsets. Then I can recreate the range with document.createRange().

What I could use guidance on is the best approach to serializing the start and end containers. My first thought was xpath, but so far my attempts have come up short. Looking at the Mozilla docs for DOM::Range seems pretty straight forward, but creating a reliable xpath to restore a range isn't quite clicking for me.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```html
<div>
    <div id="container" style="background-color: red;">
        <p id="paraText">Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### JavaScript

```js
function serialize(node) {
    if (typeof XMLSerializer != "undefined") {  // Firefox, etc.
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node);
    }
    else if (node.xml) {  // IE
        return node.xml;
    }
};

function parseXMLString(xml) {
    if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined") {  // Firefox, etc.
       var dp = new DOMParser();
       return dp.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
    }
    else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined") {  // IE
        var doc = XML.newDocument();
        doc.loadXML(xml);
        return doc;
    }
};

var contextNode = document.getElementById('container');
var xmlString = serialize(contextNode);
var doc = parseXMLString(xmlString);

// Get elements from document using XPath
var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('//.', doc.firstChild, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

// Insert elements back into document (I used replace in order to show that the document is actually changed)
contextNode.parentNode.replaceChild(xpathResult.singleNodeValue.firstChild, contextNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, I have written a solution for this for my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. The [Serializer module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) uses XPath-like syntax to serialize and deserialize ranges and selections ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html)).

I've also written a highlighter module that isn't yet released publicly. I'll tidy it and put up a demo shortly.

**UPDATE**

[Highlighter demo is now available](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html). After some more testing, it will be released in the next version of Rangy.

Comment: This was a great help, and thanks for sharing the Rangy library. Wish I would have seen this months ago.

Comment: Is there any way to read the serialized results in python. In other words if I want to send the serialized range to a python backend for processing?

Comment: @AlexRothberg: Your Python would need access to the same DOM that the JavaScript had in order to reconstruct the range in any meaningful way. Assuming you have that (big assumption), deserialization is pretty simple.

Comment: In this case the html is static. Is there documentation as to how you serialize the range?

Comment: @AlexRothberg: You'll still need to parse the HTML into a DOM representation. I've just added documentation about the serialization structure: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule

Comment: @TimDown Thank you; makes sense. Would you elaborate on how you calculate the checksum?

Comment: @AlexRothberg: It's a CRC-32 checksum generated from a custom string representation of the DOM. The easiest way to describe it is [the code](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/trunk/src/js/modules/rangy-serializer.js) (see line 84 onwards). The checksum is optional anyway.

Comment: @TimDown I am having a hard time re-creating the serialized range. Rangy is giving me "0/1/1/2:0,0/1/1/2:11" for the first instance of "Bookmarklet" on http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem with [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library's Serialiazer module is that it is not crossbrowser consistent such as the selections stored on one browser cannot be restored on a different family of browser (Gecko & IE)